# Count all rows and return values based on frequency

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I want to do a query that will count all the 'email' rows in my table and return all the values based on frequency. I don't want to group the results though, I want to show every variation of the result, here is what I have so far, as you can see it sorts by frequency but merges them by group, I'd just prefer to show them all but in order of frequency.

```
select email 
from uploads 
group by email
order by count(*) desc
```

SQL -

```
CREATE TABLE uploads 
(
 email varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO uploads
(email)
VALUES
('test@email.com'),
('test@email.com'),
('test@email.com'),
('test2@email.com'),
('test2@email.com'),
('test3@email.com'),
('test4@email.com');
```

Here Is the result I'd like

```
|              EMAIL |
----------------------
|    test@email.com  |
|    test@email.com  |
|    test@email.com  |
|    test2@email.com |
|    test2@email.com |
|    test3@email.com |
|    test4@email.com |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can join against a subquery that returns an aggregate `COUNT()` per email and order by the descending count:

```
SELECT 
  uploads.EMAIL
FROM
  uploads 
  JOIN (
    /* subquery returns distinct emails and their aggregate COUNT() */
    /* JOIN matches every row in `uploads` to the email and count */
    SELECT EMAIL, COUNT(*) as num FROM uploads GROUP BY EMAIL
  ) c ON uploads.EMAIL = c.EMAIL
ORDER BY 
  c.num DESC, 
  EMAIL ASC
```

Effectively, this produces a result like the following, though you don't actually include the `num` column in the `SELECT` list:

```
|              EMAIL | num |
----------------------------
|    test@email.com  | 3
|    test@email.com  | 3
|    test@email.com  | 3
|    test2@email.com | 2
|    test2@email.com | 2
|    test3@email.com | 1
|    test4@email.com | 1
```